# unable to perform OCR on tiff and jpeg files

Tags: alfresco

I am referring to " https://github.com/keensoft/alfresco-simple-ocr" to perform OCR on tiff and jpeg files but is saying "Couldn't find trailer dictionary","Couldn't read xref table"," exception Failure("Error: pdfinfo could not determine number of pages. Check the pdf input file.\n")" although the transformation from jpeg or tiff files to PDF files is working properly and the PDF file is visible on the alfresco share page" but no OCR is working on those tiff and jpeg files

Comment: Hi. You can look at my project too (https://github.com/bchevallereau/alfresco-tesseract). It's based on Tesseract.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are many tools which are used for performing the OCR on pdf files.It depends on the tool as well.There is one bug in alfresco.It is an library issue.Below are details of that.

---

Create file called transformation.sh and before adding your command in it you have to add below line in it.If you are using windows you need to create batch file accordingly.

unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH

If you are not setting above in the script file you will face an error while conversation.You can find that bug details on below link of alfresco.Its registered issue in alfresco.

https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-19946

PDF to PDF conversation are very well explained in below link.

http://www.krutikjayswal.com/2016/07/ocr-on-pdf-file-in-alfresco.html

You might need to change the source code for tiff conversation.